# How to properly configure magento to include a file upload link during an order notification? integrated with joomla magebridge component

Tags: php, magento, joomla, e-commerce, magento-1.5

Our website is a printing type service and it has the capacity to take the order of customers with the following procedures:

They select the type of product that they want to order
Select the paper size and the quantity of the item
The customer needs to upload a file in pdf format (This is the file to which they include the design that want for their order)
The system will send an email to both the customer and the owner (The email should include the direct link on which the uploaded file should be downloaded)

The emails are successfully sent with the details of what items they want to order. A link is included on the email but what it displays is this sample code:

Item    Sku     Qty     Subtotal
Letterhead 100gsm Matte A5 500

File Upload - File will upload after you click Buy Now

```
<a href="https://www.mydomain.com/" target="_blank"></a>
```

The "`<a href="https://www.mydomain.com/" target="_blank"></a>`" should be the download link of the pdf file that the customer have uploaded on the server. I need help on this were currently using Magento 1.5.1.0 and I have been wondering were the bug is on how to include the proper link to the pdf file uploaded by the customer.

And also we have a joomla version of the site which is using a magebridge component the main purpose of the component is to connect joomla with a magento site to enable joomla to integrate some of the important functionalities of magento. So basically users would visit the joomla site and do the transactions they need to do.

Thanks

Comment: Have you already managed to find the template to manipulate this and are solely trying to find the link generator for the file? or do you yet need to find the email template AND the link generator for the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a link to the file that was uploaded in customer's email confirmation in magento v1.7.

Copy this template file to your local template folder /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

Then change this line (#37)

```
 <?php echo (isset($option['print_value'] ) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value']))) ?>
```

to

```
 <?php echo (isset($option['print_value'] )  && $option['option_type'] != 'file' ? $option['print_value'] : $option['value']) ?>
```

This may or may not work in version 1.5.1

Comment: Thanks for the solution sorry the bounty have expired before I have confirmed your answer but this is the exact answer that I really need. Thanks to you. You really deserve the bounty though

Comment: by the way I have tried to use the line of code that you suggested here but it's the one causing the issue so I have used a different way <a href="<?php echo 'https://www.mydomain.com'.'/'.'index.php/'.$file['url']['route'].'/id/'.$file['url']['params']['id'].'/key/'.$file['url']['params']['key']; ?>"><?php echo $file['title']; ?></a>
                this one works. Maybe the original code didn't work because the orders are being made from joomla and it's connecting to magento site with the use of webservice so links are having problems displaying from there so I have to include it manually